# convert cyclic to acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, cyclic-graph

I want to convert a cyclic graph into an acyclic graph. Is there an pseudocode that can do this? I did try to search but most of them returned where mathematical based on markov chain or research articles.

I want to write a program to do it and any directions will be useful. for example consider this below graph.

```
A->B
B->C
C->A
```

I saw a solution in an **MIT** lecture but the lecture skimmed over it with reference to something taught earlier and couldn't catch it. In short it kind of replicates the nodes in layers in a way that the end graph denotes a **DAG** but conveys the same path information.

**[See 46:59]**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQ5jsbhAv_M
*Edit*:
There is an explanation of turning cyclic graphs into dags in this MIT recitation at 36:57
https://youtu.be/IFrvgSvZA0I

Se also Wikipedia : [cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) and [forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Forest)
**Edit:**

I want to apply dynamic programming over a problem which is a cyclic graph *e.g)* say shortest path problem `Delta(S,D) where S-> Source node and D->Destination node`. Since DP over cyclic graph is infinite algorithm, we first need to convert the cyclic graph into acyclic graph and then apply the dynamic programming technique over it.

Comment: What do you mean by converting a cyclic graph into an acyclic one? Finding a maximal spanning forest? Something else? Maybe the meaning of your question is in the linked video, but questions on s-o are ideally self-contained, so perhaps you could include relevant details in the text of the question?

Comment: @PaulHankin I have added a few comments, not sure if that clarifies enough.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you pointed out the wrong video, here it is (46:59): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQ5jsbhAv_M

The idea exposed here, is to make several copies of the graph and to arrange them into layers. Each one represents the state of the graph at a given time, and for every edge traversed you go down by one layer.
I did not find pseudo-code for this, but the way of doing this is detailed here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/combinatorics-of-bellman-ford-or-how-to-make-cyclic-graphs-acyclic

Comment: Thakns. I thought that question was not answered as well. Will check that again.

Comment: what i don't understand about that lecture is that he puts v in the second slot. shouldn't it be in the third slot?